# client denied by server configuration

Tags: magento2, error, shopping-cart-price-rules

when I try to apply coupon code in server its showing 403 forbidden error . But its working on local machine. below the error. please check it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
     <title>403 Forbidden</title>
     </head><body>
     <h1>Forbidden</h1>
     <p>You don't have permission to access 
     /Amberly/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/coupons/AMBIBSBHTTP
      on this server.<br />
      </p>
      <p>Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
       error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
  </body></html>
```

how can i solve this issue?.

Comment: which OS is running on your local and on the server? it could be because of permissions. Check these two things

1. Did you create rest user with proper permissions?
2. Is the error same with HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: os ubuntu 14.04. how to create rest user?. how to give rest permission to all users.

Answer (score 1):

> This error caused by apache2 server configuration.

When I edit httpd.conf file with following code the error fixed. And its working fine.

```
<Directory "your directory here">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: in log file: ::::: AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/bbppco/mg.project.co/vendor/saveprofile  

---  i have same issue how i can fix that.......

Comment: Did you checked your httpd.conf file?

Comment: how i can check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559274/client-denied-by-server-configuration-app-etc-config-php?rq=1

Comment: <Directory "your directory here">    in servers which type of path